# Database disconnection during data import

Tags: mysql, database, server, cpanel

I was importing a 11MB file into my database which contained a lot of records. For some reason phpmyadmin was not responding after a while neither was many websites on the server which use mysql. I restarted the mysql service and everything was fine. I still cant figure why it did this to me and was hoping i can find a answer here.

Answer (score 0):

By default phpmyadmin  will allow only 2mb file . Please change the configuration to upload your file.

Comment: my phpmyadmin default is 50MB